Highlight log lines in Python Dash Textarea
A log file is created in a Python Script using the library, logging.
log.info("Process started on ",t1)
log.info("Total number of files ", n)
log.info("Process completed on ",t2)

Then the file is loaded to Dash for displaying. The log file content is displayed as a textarea.
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, callback, Output, Input
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id="location"),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.H1("log display"), width=12)
    ]),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(
            dcc.Textarea(
                id='file-content',
                value='',
                readOnly=True,
                style={'width': '100%', 'height': '500px'}
            ),
            width=10
        ),
    ]),
])

I want to highlight the line that contains "Total number of files". Also there can be a few other lines that need to be highlighted.

Unfortunately, you cannot colour lines within the HTML Textarea component easily. Here is a reference to a Stackoverflow answer that talks to the details of this.
What you could do for example, is swap the dcc.Textarea for a html.Div and give it the appropriate styling you want to make it look like a text area and then use HTML components that can be easily coloured (eg. a html.Span). You can also set contentEditable='true' to make the text within the Div editable, just like a Textarea. Here is an example:
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, callback, Output, Input
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = Dash()

# Sample log file content
log_content = """Process started on 2024-05-16 10:00:00
Total number of files 10
Some other log line
Process completed on 2024-05-16 10:30:00"""


# # Function to highlight specific lines
@app.callback(
    Output("file-content", "children"),
    Input("file-content", "children"),
)
def highlight_log(_):
    lines = log_content.split("\n")
    highlighted_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        if "Total number of files" in line:
            highlighted_lines.append(html.Span(line, style={"color": "red"}))
        else:
            highlighted_lines.append(html.Span(line))
        highlighted_lines.append(html.Br())
    return highlighted_lines


app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Location(id="location"),
        dbc.Row([dbc.Col(html.H1("Log Display"), width=12)]),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    html.Div(
                        id="file-content",
                        style={"width": "100%", "height": "500px"},
                        contentEditable="true",
                    ),
                    width=10,
                ),
            ]
        ),
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)

Here is how the above code looks like, when editing it:

